# Phantom style in django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on my first real django project, and was fiddling around with the css, but the changes I made did not have any effect on the site. I tried changing things on all 3 of the css files but nothing changed. I then deleted the files (from the project I still have them), and still nothing changed. My site is getting styled, I checked all of my html to make sure there was no inline style in there. All the html files are working, when I change them the site changes. Is this some weird caching thing? I've tried rerunning the server several times and still my site is getting style, seemingly from nowhere. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your site from now on in incognito mode. I think it is some weird caching thing so maybe clear your cache too. When developing I just use igcognito and static updates just fine.

Comment: @LiamClawson-Honyeman - You're welcome. Please mark as the answer if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django copies static files (like CSS) in a separate directory when you're running with `DEBUG=False`. If you update any of the static files in your project, you'll have to run the `collectstatic` command to update them.

From the root of your project, try:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```